# dynamically rename tkinter window

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have the following bits of code that creates a toplevel window and parses a dictionary into a Text widget:

```
def escrito(**kwargs):
    write_window = Toplevel(root)
    #write_window.title(kwargs) (problematic code)
    writing_box = tk.Text(write_window, font = ("calibri", 20), width  = 60, height = 15, wrap=WORD)
    writing_box.pack(expand = tk.YES, fill = tk.X)
    writing_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nswe')
    texto = '\n'.join(key + ":\n" + value for key, value in kwargs.items())
    writing_box.insert("1.0", texto)

def septic_osteo():
    escrito(**infections.Septic_arthritis)
Septic_arthritis = {
'Empirical Treatment':
'Flucloxacillin 2g IV 6-hourly',
'If non-severe penicillin allergy':
'Ceftriaxone IV 2g ONCE daily',
'If severe penicillin allergy OR if known to be colonised with 
MRSA':
'Vancomycin infusion IV, Refer to  Vancomycin Prescribing 
Policy',
'If systemic signs of sepsis': 'Discuss with Consultant 
Microbiologist'
}
```

So when I run the code, the escrito functions parses the dictionary and writes its content onto a text widget contained on a Toplevel window. What I would like to know is how to dynamically rename the Toplevel window with the dicitonary's name. I do know that I can do this:

```
def septic_osteo():
    escrito(**infections.Septic_arthritis)
    write_window.title('Septic_arthritis)
```

but I do have like 100 functions like the one above, so, aside from labour intensive, I am not sure is the more pythonic way, so, is there a way that the window can be renamed with the dictionary name? (i.e. 'Septic_arthritis)
Thanks

Comment: `kwargs.get(key,default)` ?

Comment: that does not work, I get the following error:  write_window.title(kwargs.get(key,default))
NameError: name 'key' is not defined

Comment: Key stands for a key in the dictionary. Can you please show a little bit more of your code. Im not entirly sure what you want to do.

Comment: Of course, say I have this dictionary:
Hospital_Acquired_Pneumonia = {
'Definition': '>72 hours after admission to a healthcare institution or a prior hospital admission within past 30 days', 'Non-severe': 'Doxycycline 200mg stat then 100mg PO once daily',
'If unable to tolerate Doxycycline or oral route not available': 'Co-trimoxazole 960mg IV 12-hourly',
'Severe': 'Piperacillin-tazobactam  IV 4.5g 8 hourly', 'If penicillin allergic': 'Levofloxacin  500mg IV / PO 12-hourly'
}
What I'd like is my window to be renamed: 'Hospital_Acquired_Pneumonia'
hope that makes more sense

Comment: You can either do some really complicated stuff for this simple task. Or you just add a key to your dictionary like `Septic_arthritis = {
'Empirical Treatment':
'Flucloxacillin 2g IV 6-hourly',
'If non-severe penicillin allergy':
'Ceftriaxone IV 2g ONCE daily',
'If severe penicillin allergy OR if known to be colonised with 
MRSA':
'Vancomycin infusion IV, Refer to  Vancomycin Prescribing 
Policy',
'If systemic signs of sepsis': 'Discuss with Consultant 
Microbiologist', 'Title':'Hospital_Acquired_Pneumonia'
}` and do `kwargs.pop('Title')`

Comment: I see, problem is, I have already defined all the dictionaries, so while that will work, it will be no different from adding a line to the function (each function refers to 1 dictionary.
Thank you, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in an object named `infections`, with attributes such as `Septic_arthritis`, the most straight-forward solution is to pass the data and the attribute as separate arguments, and then use `getattr` to get the data for the particular infection.

It would look something like this:

```
def escrito(data, infection):

    write_window = Toplevel(root)
    write_window.title(infection)
    writing_box = tk.Text(write_window, font = ("calibri", 20), width  = 60, height = 15, wrap="word")
    writing_box.pack(expand = tk.YES, fill = tk.X)
    writing_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nswe')
    texto = '\n'.join(key + ":\n" + value for key, value in getattr(data, infection).items())
    writing_box.insert("1.0", texto)
```

The important bit about the above code is that it uses `getattr(data, infection)` to get the data for the given infection.

If you want to create a button to call this function, it might look something like this:

```
button = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: escrito(infections, "Septic_arthritis"))
```

This will call the command `escrito` with two arguments: the object that contains all of the infections, and the key to the specific piece of information you want to display.

Comment: Thank you so much, I need to get my head around how getattr works here, but it does work.